# What is the latest and stable QGIS version support SAGA with Multilevel B-Spline interpolation

Tags: qgis, interpolation, saga

I am trying to interpolate elevation points to create a digital elevation model (DEM) on QGIS (v3.22.13). One previous research suggests that Multilevel B-Spline interpolation (MBI) in SAGA is the best option for that task. However, the SAGA version 7.8.2 is not offered on my current QGIS.
What is the latest and most stable QGIS version that can use SAGA with MBI?

[image]

Comment: The message say that SAGA 7.8.2 is not OFFICIALLY supported and that it MAY encounter issues but not that it will not work or give wrong result. Did you try to use it and if yes did did you encounter any problem ? Also you may use SAGA as a standalone application...

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use **portable** ltr version eg. 3.18.3 https://portable.info.pl/qgis-portable/